# Decimal Pipe in Angular 2 - Commas Only, No Decimal Places

Tags: angular, numbers, decimal, angular2-pipe

I currently use this pipe `{{ product.productPrice | number:'.2-2' }}`

And result is 1,000,000.00 but I want to remove the `.00`
How do you do that?

Comment: @Vega: The edits were only on the title (from the OP, more descriptive) and from me (removed an inadequate tag), I don't think anything substantial from the question has been changed.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use this :

```
  {{product.productPrice | number: '1.0-0'}}
```

1.0-0 means: at least one digit before decimal point, 0 digits after decimal point.

The general format is:

> `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`
>
> minIntegerDigits: The minimum number of integer digits before the
> decimal point. Default is 1.
> minFractionDigits: The minimum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.
> maxFractionDigits: The
> maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: what if I have 10 (100.10) after digit and don't want to remove it but want to remove if it is 100.00? do I need to handle it separately?

Comment: is it possible just get one digit before decimal point without rounding up? I mean `-1.75` should be `1`, not `2`?

Comment: @StepUp, Angular decimal pipe rounds down and for the negative numbers that means up as a an absolute number. You can use just Math.trunc() before applying the pipe? Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbongy

Comment: @Vega I am sorry, however I cannot see your code. Could you show, please, your code? I see just a page with code, however without `Math.trunc()`.

Comment: I've seen `Main.ts` and `polyfill.ts` files, however there is no `Math.trunc()`. May be this file is not saved. Could you post here your code?

Comment: @Vega this {{ 3000 | number: '1.0-0' }} return 3.000, why?

Comment: @juanjinario, 3.000 is just formatted for thousands, it is not a decimal number. What are you looking to achieve?